# How to install Spacy on 32bit windows?

Tags: python, nlp, 32bit-64bit, spacy

I am using Python 3.6 and windows 7 (32 bit).

While installing spacy using pip command I encounter the following error:

```
Failed building wheel for srsly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 64-bit is supported, sorry!